# How does one set up a simple local development environment for micro-services using YAML for Kubernetes in Docker?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

My goal is straightforward, I wish to start simple.  One micro-service using Spring Boot running on one Docker container, a second micro-service running on another Docker container and a Web-based UI running on a third Docker container.

The goal is to not only have the micro-services communicate with one another through a common URI, but also have the Web application be able to communicate with them as seamlessly as possible.  I will be using Nginx as a reverse proxy for the Web UI to find services.

For example, micro-service 1 should be called by using /api/service1, and the second service /api/service2.  The Web application has a front-facing URL and it's JavaScript code delegates to the services when needed.

I'd like to be able to use go to "mysite.com", which brings up the main page; however, I could possibly navigate to "mysite.com/api/service1" or "mysite.com/api/service2" and still get a response, even though these the Web site and the two services are running in separate containers.

So, on my local machine, how could I set up three container applications, two for each of the services and the other running a Web site, so they all can still communicate with one another and the entire orchestration can be seen from an outside observer?

I would like to orchestrate this using Kubernetes (I am using KIND [Kubernetes in Docker]), but my ultimate goal is to set up a development environment on a local machine to simulate a Cloud environment and use best practices in doing so;  Apparently doing this declaratively in YAML is what is required, but looking at the documentation, with services, nodeports, pods, namespaces, etc, it's quite a confusing trek.  I recently started creating pods and found out they deployments were preferred for "best practices".

I'm running in a Windows environment, I use Docker for Windows (Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89).  I've enabled the Kubernetes support for Docker for the purposes of creating deployments.  I'm using a Docker image for the Oracle server built using the instructions here (https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance) Note: Windows users, please edit those scripts and make them all conform to Unix line endings.

I'm using Spring Boot Tools Suite (basically the one which is bundled with Eclipse) to create simple micro-services, Nginx on its own instance as a reverse proxy and still yet one other instance for dishing up the Web content.

This is an example YAML file I used for the purposes of running the same image under the guise of two different services:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: dev
  labels:
    name: dev
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: echo-api
  namespace: dev
spec:
  selector:
    name: echo-api
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: echo-api
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: echo2-api
  namespace: dev
spec:
  selector:
    name: echo2-api
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: echo2-api
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: echo-api
  namespace: dev
  labels:
    name: echo-api
spec:
  hostname: echo-api
  subdomain: default-subdomain
  containers:
  - image: echo-api:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    name: echo-api
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: echo2-api
  namespace: dev
  labels:
    name: echo2-api
spec:
  hostname: echo2-api
  subdomain: default-subdomain
  containers:
  - image: echo-api:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    name: echo2-api
```

What I am trying to accomplish is completing this with the proper YAML that uses best practices; the set-up a Web site and micro-services, all running on conceptually "different" virtual containers, yet still allow for a debugging environment on a local machine.  A container running NGinx (aside from the Web site itself) would be used as a reverse-proxy to communicate with the services.

I am trying to achieve a configurable end-result of a local development environment which can allow for rapid development and testing of microservices in a simulated, complete end-to-end orchestrated environment before they are even deployed to the Cloud.

Comment: Look into “nginx ingress controller” which will run nginx and allow you to configure routing rules so that different paths off the mysite.com domain can route to different Services which each respectively expose different Pods/Deployments. Ingress resources are expressed declaratively in YAML, just like Services and Deployments.

Comment: I think you are trying to mix a lot of things here, maybe you should proceed step by step. First, dockerize your spring boot applications. Setup your dataflow and test on a local machine by running dockerized applications on your local machine. Because kubernetes is a whole another beast to tame.

Comment: My step zero, even before running things in Docker, would be to write the two applications in a plain-Java environment, no Docker, and test and debug them there.  Then build Docker images and try to deploy them into a Kubernetes environment.

Comment: @DavidMaze, thank you for the advice, but we are inheriting a project that was already developed and deployed to the cloud.  The team inheriting this project has very little experience with several of the technologies used and I am tasked with setting up a local development environment as a 'recipe' other developers can use to continue developing and maintaining the product, simulating its behavior as close as possible to the cloud environment while allowing them to debug the application (basically a collection of microservices).

Comment: @damitj07, you are correct, I am mixing a lot of things and I had to start learning each one individually to get the basics first.  We've inherited an existing project which does have a lot of moving parts.  A member of our DevOps team is putting together a pipeline for building, running unit tests, automated tests, packaging and deploying; however, I just need the ability to run our unit tests, package and deploy for debugging on a local machine, each user running their own database.  I did finally get the configuration I needed, using Deployments instead of Pods.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta, we are using Docker for Windows with Linux containers and its integrated single-node Kubernetes; however, the Ingress is experimental and when attempting to set it up, I received several errors about it attempting to use port numbers with higher values than Windows could seem to handle.  Needless to say, I was gun-shy about the results, so decided to instead use Nginx as a reverse proxy and route each of the requests to the correct service based on the URI.  I am able to get the machines to communicate now, so I'm more hopeful in getting this approach to work.

Comment: Were you able to accomplish your goal or do you still have any issues related with Kubernetes?

Comment: @PjoterS, I am about 98% of the way there.  I have set up the following: a) Docker for Windows with Kubernetes (using Linux containers); b) a Kubernetes single-node cluster running the following: an Oracle 18c XE instance, Nginx acting as a reverse-proxy for the microservices and each microservices in its own Pod (with Services to expose the debug ports for the Jar files).  The Web application is actually not running in the cluster, but it makes requests to the URL on the local machine handled by the reverse proxy.  It took about two weeks of research, but I finally have something lucrative.